# how can i change one of these classes to enable me to allow the student to take multiple tests with multiple marks?

Tags: java

as i said before, i am wondering how can i change one of these classes to enable me to allow the student to take multiple tests with multiple marks?

here is the first class

```
public class Student {

 private String name;
 private int noOfExams;
 private double totalMark;

public Student (String name, int noOfExams, double totalMark) {
    this.name = name;
    this.noOfExams = noOfExams;
    this.totalMark = totalMark;     
}
public void setName (String Name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setnoOfExams (int noOfExams) {
    this.noOfExams = noOfExams;
}
public void settotalMark (double totalMark) {
    this.totalMark = totalMark;
}

public String getName (){
    return name;
}
public int getnoOfExams (){
    return noOfExams;
}
public double gettotalMark() {
    return totalMark;
}
public  double getAverageMark () {
    return (totalMark/noOfExams);
}
}
```

Here is the tester class

```
public class studentTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student Padraig = new Student ("Padraig" , 1 , 40); 

    System.out.println("The Student's name is : " + Padraig.getName());
    System.out.println("The Student has took " + Padraig.getnoOfExams() + " exams");
    System.out.println("The Student's Mark is " + Padraig.gettotalMark());
}
}
```

Comment: Like, an array of exams?

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you, so you please spend the 1 minute it takes to really properly format/indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

I won't do your homework for you, but here some thoughts to get you started.

First, you have to learn about [arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm) or [Lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm). You simply need such data structures in order to "store" the multiple values that come with that plural in "multiple tests".

Then you would add a method like

```
public void addTest(String testName, int mark)
```

to your class. That method would then take the incoming information and **add** that to those arrays/lists created before. And then your "tester" code simply calls that add method repeatedly, to add multiple tests.

Finally, you would add a method such as

```
public List<String> getTestNames()
```

or

```
public List<Integer> getTestMarks()
```

that would allow to retrieve that additional information.

"arrays" are the more fundamental/basic/built-in concept; so they are a bit easier to understand (less context knowledge required); but Lists are more dynamic. So, your choice how much energy you want to spend (if you are really interested in learning, you simply try both).

The final step would be to use a better abstraction. The above example looks at a test as an "informal" pair of "test name" and "mark". That would mean: two lists with different values. Insted, you could create a class

```
public class Test {
 ... fields for name, mark, ...
```

that wraps around this information. And then you can do even more things, like looking into an equals method for such objects ...

Thus: many many many things you can do here - you just need to get going.

Answer (score 0):

To have them take multiple marks just have it surrounded in a while loop and if you wanted to make it random questions each time just place multiple questions in something like a hash map.

Example:

```
HashMap questions<Integer, String> = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

Random questionNumber = new Random();

questions.put(1, "What is 1+1");

While(takingTest == true) {

// don't put 10 if you have less than 10 questions; 0-9
System.out.println(question.get(questionNumber.nextInt(10)));

// make sure to be able to close the loop as this is an example

}
```

If you get all the questions multiple times constantly its because you never had the ability to end your while loop

Note: if something is wrong with the code its because I am not at my workstation to test it. This is more of a general answer